# Microsoft Teams Fast Tenant Switch is not showing immediately

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We enabled guest access in our tenant as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/guest-access-checklist. We invited User-A who is another tenant using invitation API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) as a guest. User-A accepts the invite and he\she is part of our Tenant but the Fast Tenant Switch is not showing for that User immediately. It is showing nearly after 24 hours.

1 . Is that usual behavior for Guest User or anything missed on the setup and\or in the invitation process.

Comment: it takes significant delay 8-24 hours to add a guest user using graph API

Comment: Thanks @Trinetra-MSFT . Even after 24 hours if  User-A login to Microsoft Teams client he\she is not able to view\access the Guest Tenant because 'Fast Tenant Switch' option is not available in the client.  But with 'Channel Deep link url' of a channel in the Guest Tenant he\she can able to access and see the 'Fast Tenant Switch' option. At the same time if he switches to his Primary Tenant the 'Fast Tenant Switch' option is not available.

Comment: Could you please look at [Fast Switching between Tenant](https://medium.com/@messageio/switching-between-microsoft-teams-accounts-and-what-to-do-about-it-7479f659665b)?

Comment: It seems for Desktop clients it takes significant amount of time and for the WebClient it is not taking that much time to show the Fast Tenant Switch. Is there an Graph API available to find the status of the guest user service enablement including Fast Tenant Switch ? So that we can inform the User accordingly.